# Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.setCellValue(String)" because "cell" is null for existing XLSM file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xlsm

I use Apache POI to write data to a predefined XLSM file. I use this code to open existing file:

```
Cell cell;
File file = new File(XLSMPath);
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(inputStream);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(recordcount+4);
```

Data is written in first iteration in the 5th row and so on. Code to set value of a given cell:

```
cell = row.getCell(CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("A"));
cell.setCellValue(myvalue);
```

It worked fine for the first 400 iterations, but after that I get following error message:

> Cannot invoke "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell.setCellValue(String)"
> because "cell" is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the worksheet cells yourself. Just check if your `Cell` is `null` and create new `Cell` using [`createCell(int)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.0/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFRow.html#createCell-int-):

```
cell = row.getCell(CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("A"));
if (cell == null) {
    // maybe in your case index should be taken in other way
    cell = row.createCell(CellReference.convertColStringToIndex("A")); 
}
cell.setCellValue(myvalue);
```

Comment: Thanks, that is ok, I just wondered, why file has 400 rows.

Comment: It also surprised me. I was looking for information on this in the documentation when I wrote the answer to your question, however I did not find information that the workbook is created with a certain number of default columns (similar to the case of rows). From my experience with the Apache POI, I can say that I have always had to create the rows and columns myself.